# Deleted my clients accidentally Magento 1.7

Tags: sql, client, backend, magento-1.7, webstore

I was deleting some spam from my client list and accidentally deleted all clients from my store M1.7.0.2
I not have backup, is it possible to restore my deleted clients?
Thanks in advance